# Filtering with django model object list using dynamic path

Tags: django, django-models

I want to consume Field lookups in the form of strings. Something like this:

```
path = "pk__in"
resources = resource_model.objects.filter(path=resource_ids)
```

I would want resources to be a list of objects from resource_model.

How can I achieve filtering with dynamic path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind dynamic parameter with `*[1, 2, 3]`, `**{'key': 'value'}` in python. [More detail](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)

example for your case:

```
filter_data = {'pk__in': resource_ids}
resources = resource_model.objects.filter(**filter_data)
```

Similar question: 
[django annotate with dynamic column name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54633353/6284315)